# TransactionRequiredException when flushing entity manager inside a UserTransaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jta, jboss-eap-7

I have a servlet that takes POST requests and I'm trying to use the parameters of the request to build and persist an instance of an entity class.

This is my servlet:

```
public class TheServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="unit1")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException {
        // parse request parameters
        // ...

        // create and persist object based on the parameters
        createInstance(parsedParameters);
    }

    private Long createInstance(ParsedParams initData) {
        MyObj instance = new MyObj(initData);

        try {
            utx.begin();
            entityManager.persist(instance);
            entityManager.flush(instance);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return instance.getId();
    }
}
```

This is the exception in the logs:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1297)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.flush(AbstractEntityManager.java:459)
    at org.mypackagename.TheServlet.createInstance(TheServlet.java:122)
    ... 44 more
```

Right before the exception I see this in the log:

```
19:50:10,222 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: 
19:50:10,223 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     select
19:50:10,223 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         MY_OBJ_SEQ.nextval 
19:50:10,223 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)     from
19:50:10,223 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)         dual
```

And if I check in the database, the nextval of the sequence has indeed been used. But the table mapped to the entity class is still empty.
If I remove the `flush()` call, I don't get the exception, but still the sequence value is selected and nothing is inserted in the table.

I'm using JBoss EAP 7 and I have set the `jta` attribute of the datasource to true.

This is my `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="unit1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I just needed to add the @Transactional annotation to the method.